# What is the equivalent of Javas Joda Time LocalDate class in cocoa touch?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

Joda time provides the java world with the `LocalDate` class. It provides you with a date only w/o time information that translates to the same date regardless of the timezone the users mobile phone or computer is set to. It allows for calculations.

Apparently it is backed with a regular `DateTime` object that is set to 13.00 UTC.

Is there an equivalent in the cocoa or cocoa-touch world?

Or am I limited to using NSDate and set it to 13:00 and a locale for UTC to achieve the same thing? That should work alike but looks more like a hack than a solution. 
I might of course just introduce a subclass of `NSDate` for it.

Comment: What are trying to accomplish, precisely?  Between NSDate, NSCalendar and NSDateComponents, you can do any time or date calculation you can think of.  Java may have a knock-off third-party class to fix their broken stuff, but Foundation did it first, and did it better!  /fighting_words

Comment: I want to set a date in any time zone. Just the date. I want it in some class that allows for calculations and < and > comparisons. I want this same date displayed as the same date everywhere in the world using local time zones there. Same as JodaTime's LocalDate does.

Comment: If there is no time portion, the time zone is irrelevant.  You can use an NSDate with the time set to 12:00 AM (00:00), and do whatever calculations you want.  It's up to you to ignore the time portion when printing or displaying the date to the user.

Comment: Also, NSDates don't have a concept of a time zone.  That interpretation is up to the programmer who is using it.

Comment: @Avi, I'd wish you were right, but you are not. The time zone is not irrelevant. Set it to 12 AM in Bejin time zone and store it somewhere. Then set your phone to San Francisco and recover it and display it. You will see the date of the day before. Do it the other way around and you will have +1 day displayed. Setting to 11 AM UTC will work in any time zone but that is not what I asked for.

Comment: @Avi NSDate follow the concept of locale and locales come with a time zone.

Comment: @Avi, correcting an earlier statement, strictly spoken NSDate does not deal with Locales itself. But the NSDate objects are displayed using DateFormatters and any Locale must be applied to the DateFormatter.

Comment: NSDates are absolute points in time.  They have **no** concept of a time zone.  What you are seeing is interpretation of that NSDate by some (combination of) class(es) that does take it into account.  As I wrote before, it's up to you to treat the NSDate as just a date.

Comment: @avi, how do you display the NSDate on screen in a way, that the date displayed is the same date regardless of locale of the device?

Comment: Set the formatter to use the UTC (not GMT) time zone.  Because NSDates are relative to UTC, formatters adjust the absolute point in time to reflect the given time zone.  That is, it's like getting the time from your friend in Los Angeles and mentally adding 3 hours because you're in New York.  The formatter "knows" that the NSDate is in UTC, so it assumes it has to mentally convert to local time for you.

Comment: That is right. However, it does not answer the question.

Comment: If you have two NSDates with the same date and time components, you have identical NSDates, no matter which time zone the device running the code is in.  So if you take the expiration date and lop off the time, and take the current date from the device and lop off the time, you have comparable NSDates.

Comment: Well, yes. Besides that, do you know any 1:1 equivalent of JodaTime's LocalDate for iOS? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt such a thing exists, given that Foundation has a collection of classes (listed in the one answer) that cover pretty much any conceivable need, unless one wants a custom calendar.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Did you ever find an equivalent?

Comment: @Questioner Apparently there isn't any.

Comment: Found this https://github.com/edwardaux/DateTimeKit Haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score -2):

Foundation has these classes when handling dates:

- [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) - Stores a point in time.
- [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) - Stores some or all calendar values for a date.
- [NSTimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html)
- [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/)
- [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/) - Is a class for making calculations with dates, given a type of calendar. It can convert between `NSDate` and `NSDateComponents` among other things.
- [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) - Converts between `NSString` and `NSDate`.

The time zone and locale for `NSCalendar` and `NSDateFormatter` can be set to any value.

See the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. What does NSDateComponents result in, when the date of - lets say - 1.1.2016 is stored in it in CET when its value is persisted somewhere and restored in Moskow or New York and then displayed using an NSDateFormater showing Date only?

Comment: It depends on the time zone of the NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Well, and that is exactly the deficiency that I want to overcome. I need it to be the same date globally but I need to be able to apply calculations and comparisons such as if a certain valid-to date has expired etc.

Comment: Is your expiration date absolute or relative to the user's time zone?

Comment: @Avi, it is absolute. Just as `LocalDate` does. That is why I asked for an equivalent of `LocalDate`.

Comment: You want to do something like `if (expDate >= today) { tell user too late; }`?

Comment: Yes, we need that too. But this is not the point of the question. I was asking for an equivalent of LocalDate of JodaTime. If that does not exist then I am happy with knowing that it does not exist. We will then either create one (based on NSDate) or use one of the well known workarounds. But when we go for LocalDate on the Android client then we need a good working equivalent on the iOS clients.

Comment: I don't understand how NSDate doesn't fulfill the requirement as-is.  Perhaps you could provide more detail on where your dates are coming form and how they are being compared.

Comment: `NSDate` is nothing like `LocalDate`. A date as we use it in normal English means a range of time from midnight to right before mid-night. `NSDate` references a specific moment in time and is a misnomer, confusing people. It doesn't fulfill many requirements. For instance, if you have a coupon that is good until Sep 3, how would you code it? Either you're going to use `< midnightOfDayAfterLastEffectiveDate` or use `<= midnightOfDayAfterLastEffectiveDate.nextDown`, which of course doesn't reflect what most coupons say and makes it confusing for everyone.